# tableView with huge dataSource ( about million rows)

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit, datasource, reload

I have a tableview with dataSource that is constantly updated with data on 100 new rows, i.e. there is a method with a cycle consisting of a million iterations, it collects data in a group of 100 elements and gives array in a callback and thereby adds elements to the datasource. I need to make sure that the tableView does not freeze when scrolling, how can I do this and when should I reload tableView?

in viewDidLoad I have:

```
server.subscribeToDeals { deals in //every time deals consists of 100 elements
            self.model.append(contentsOf: deals) //dataSource expands
}
```

I tried to use UITableViewDiffableDataSource but tableView still freeze when scrolling

Comment: You can prefetch data when scrolling, If your data has images , you can cache them or try to load images async ... It's hard to give a clear answer without knowing how it works.

Comment: How is a user going to meaningfully navigate a table view with a million rows?

Comment: @jrturton user can filter table by parameters as date, price and etc.